# Error linter doesn't show red underline in project path GoLand

Tags: go, jetbrains-ide, goland

If we have an error in go code, for example `Not enough argument to return` we will see red error underline in project path GoLand like this:

[image]

But, why it does not shown when linter error? For example when there is unused variable or when I set a variable with struct type with `nil`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue, should be addressed in the 2020.2 release of GoLand. For details/updates watch/vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-3378

Meanwhile, to quickly get to errors in the current file, use F2.